# customView in LinearLayout fills space

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a custom view `MaskCustomView` by subclassing View. The width/height layout params for the custom view are both WRAP_CONTENT.

What happens is the custom view in the LinearLayout takes all the space. I can see that using uiautomatorViewer :

[image: image here]

Code is :

```
public class MaskImageView extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mask_image);

    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.maskID);

    MaskCustomView maskView = new MaskCustomView(this);
    maskView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    container.addView(maskView);
}


public class MaskCustomView extends View {

    private Bitmap bp;
    private Paint p;

    public MaskCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        bp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.apple);
        p = new Paint();

    }



    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 0, 0 , p);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

}
}
```

xml layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/maskID"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Shouldn't just wrap content and don't use whole space for both height and width ?

Comment: post the `mask_image` xml

Comment: Why aren't you using a simple ImageView to achieve this? It will automatically respect the width and height.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin xml layout posted.

Comment: @SimonMarquis yes I know that but I don't understand what's wrong with that code. Plus I want to add more stuff after this works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to make your `MaskCustomView` override `onMeasure`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(bp == null) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    } else {
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(bp.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.MODE_CONSTANT), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(bp.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.MODE_CONSTANT);
    }    
}
```

Comment: yeap that's seems the only way.